# Why itertools combinations returns empty list?

Tags: python

From Python terminal I am trying to get all the tuples for my string.

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> TUPLES = list(combinations(['picaacd'], 2))
>>> TUPLES
[]
```

Why is `TUPLES` an empty list?

Comment: what is the expected output? do you want combinations of letters? `TUPLES = list(combinations('picaacd', 2))`

Comment: How many different combinations of two things from a list of _only one thing_ did you expect to get?

Answer (score 1):

[Combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of 2 values require at least 2 items in your population. Here your population is only one string ('picaacd'), thus there is nothing to output.

For instance:

```
list(combinations(['strA'], 2))
# []

list(combinations(['strA', 'strB'], 2))
# [('strA', 'strB')]

list(combinations(['strA', 'strB', 'strC'], 2))
# [('strA', 'strB'), ('strA', 'strC'), ('strB', 'strC')]
```

You can compute the number of items in the output with the formula `n!/(k!*(n-k)!)`, which in your case is `0` (because n=1, k=2).

Using python:

```
from math import comb

comb(1, 2)
# 0
```

---

If you want to get the combinations of letters, then use:

```
TUPLES = list(combinations('picaacd', 2))
```

Output:

```
[('p', 'i'),
 ('p', 'c'),
 ('p', 'a'),
 ('p', 'a'),
 ('p', 'c'),
 ('p', 'd'),
 ('i', 'c'),
 ('i', 'a'),
 ('i', 'a'),
 ('i', 'c'),
 ('i', 'd'),
 ('c', 'a'),
 ('c', 'a'),
 ('c', 'c'),
 ('c', 'd'),
 ('a', 'a'),
 ('a', 'c'),
 ('a', 'd'),
 ('a', 'c'),
 ('a', 'd'),
 ('c', 'd')]
```